# Host a Web Service in IIS with Sharepoint using Port 80

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-7, sharepoint-2010

I have a Sharepoint Server, I published an asp.net Web Service and I want to host it in IIS. Port 80 is being used by Sharepoint. How do I host this web service on my local machine successfully? Thanks

Comment: Use a different port or use a different site.

Answer (score 0):

You don't, you cannot host 2 different things on the same port. However, you could host the web service **within** SharePoint. Do the following:

- Copy the .dll file of the web service in the GAC (*global assembly cache C:\windows\assembly*)
- Copy the .asmx file in the LAYOUTS folder (*C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS*)
- iisreset
- access the web service http://sharepointserver/_layouts/myservice.asmx

Answer (score 0):

If you have a different domain name for you web service, you should create another binding for it.

Just create new IIS application, go to Binding options, put "myservice.com" (should be different from your share point site domain) and port 80;